# Show with the definition that the function $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $f(x,y,z) = (x^2-y^2+z, 4|xy|)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Show with the definition that the function $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to
>  \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $f(x,y,z) = (x^2-y^2+z, 4|xy|)$ is
>   continuous.

Let $\alpha=(x,y,z), \alpha_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \mathbb{R^3}$

For $\delta > 0$, $||\alpha - \alpha_0||< \delta$ $ \implies$ $$||f(\alpha)- f(\alpha_0)||$$ $$=||((x^2 - x_0^2)-(y^2-y_0^2)+(z-z_0), 4(|xy|-|x_0y_0|))||$$

Can I use the Cauchy-Scharwz inequality and use an equivalent norm, i.e. $||\cdot||_\infty$?

How can I continue to cleverly develop this equality? Is there an inequality I can use to simplify or I have to develop the right side of the equality? I know I have to factorized the first few terms $(x^2 - x_0^2)$ and $(y^2-y_0^2)$ with $4(|xy|-|x_0y_0|)$

Comment: Sum of continuous functions is continuous. Co-ordinate functions are continuous.

Comment: @Mambo I know this is true, but I can't use it by the only fact that we have not seen this theorem so far. So I have to use the full definition.